# how to login https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ in personal test account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

i have made an account on https://developer.paypal.com/ and after that create a personal account and a business account now i want to test these account to make a transaction on sandbox but on sandbox  there is a problem that i can't get access to login as personal account and as  business account https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/    i used the email address and password of my personal account and business account .   how i can do test on paypal sandbox ?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, explain your question more properly

Answer (score 1):

I am also passing through these phases, anyway after just logged in at https://developer.paypal.com/ with your paypal acount that you created at https://www.paypal.com/, you will found an an application menu there, and on the left side you will found sandbox_accounts, paypal will automatically create your merchant account, this merchant account will be used as a seller in paypal api, and you personal account will be used for transaction like payment.